# how can I run and debug arm c code in code composer studio(ccs7) with out an external hardware?

Tags: arm, embedded

I am trying to run a program in ccs7. But I do not have that particular hardware. can I run or debug without hardware?

Comment: Do you mean without target hardware or without a hardware debugger interface?  Buy hardware or downgrade to CCSv5 which includes simulators.  http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/List_of_Simulator

Comment: yes you are right. CCS does not  include simulators after CCSv5. Thank you